# Order of execution when reading from buffered channel in goroutine

Tags: go

I was playing around with concurrency and buffered channels and I hit upon the following problem that left me confused:
https://play.golang.org/p/wir7wP2u-yf

1. Why exactly does the 'unload' of the channel (of size 3) inside the function echo happen with the 4 included?
2. Why does the capacity of the channel c stay 0 after 5 is sent to the channel?
3. Why is 10 not echoed?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func echo(c chan int) {
    for num := range c {
        //fmt.Printf("length of channel c: %v\n",len(c))
        fmt.Println(num)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done iterating")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan int, 3)

    go echo(c)

    c <- 1
    fmt.Printf("After 1, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 2
    fmt.Printf("After 2, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 3
    fmt.Printf("After 3, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 4 // blocks here
    fmt.Printf("After 4, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 5
    fmt.Printf("After 5, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 6
    fmt.Printf("After 6, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 7
    fmt.Printf("After 7, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 8
    fmt.Printf("After 8, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 9
    fmt.Printf("After 9, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 10
    fmt.Printf("After 10\n")
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

Comment: You're not checking capacity, you're checking length, capacity doesn't change. `echo` is running concurrently, so it could receive and print the values _any_ time after they've been sent to the channel.

Answer (score -1):

It entirely depends on OS scheduling. The results of the above code would not be always the same.

```golang
main() started
After 1, capacity 1
After 2, capacity 2
After 3, capacity 3
1
2
3
4
After 4, capacity 0
After 5, capacity 0
After 6, capacity 1
After 7, capacity 2
After 8, capacity 3
5
6
7
8
9
After 9, capacity 0
After 10
main() stopped
```

This result might be the same as you saw in the playground. But, it is unpredictable because we can't determine how OS schedule the execution order of goroutines.

If I run this code in my local machine, It will be different every time I execute it. See below:

First run

```golang
main() started
After 1, capacity 1
After 2, capacity 1
After 3, capacity 2
1
2
3
4
After 4, capacity 3
After 5, capacity 0
5
After 6, capacity 0
After 7, capacity 1
After 8, capacity 2
After 9, capacity 3
6
7
8
9
10
After 10
main() stopped
```

Second run

```golang
main() started
After 1, capacity 1
After 2, capacity 2
1
2
3
After 3, capacity 2
After 4, capacity 0
4
5
After 5, capacity 1
After 6, capacity 0
After 7, capacity 1
After 8, capacity 2
6
7
8
9
After 9, capacity 3
After 10
main() stopped
10
```

So answers to your questions would be

1. Receiving the channel (for 4) just was executed before `fmt.Printf` in the main function. It could be different every execution. Try it on your local machine.
2. Similar to 1. It just read by `range` before `len(c)`.
3. The main goroutine exited before reading the 10 from the channel. In this case, you should wait for all items in the channel will be read using some techniques such as time sleeping, wait group of sync package or another channel.

You can see how that program works by inserting the `time.Sleep(time.Second)` between the lines you want to inspect.

For example, if you sleep for 1 second before `fmt.Println("main() stopped")`, you can see always the `10` echo because the main goroutine will be waiting for a second. (1 second is big enough for reading an item from the channel)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func echo(c chan int) {
    for num := range c {
        fmt.Println(num)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done iterating")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan int, 3)

    go echo(c)

    c <- 1
    fmt.Printf("After 1, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 2
    fmt.Printf("After 2, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 3
    fmt.Printf("After 3, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 4 // blocks here
    fmt.Printf("After 4, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 5
    fmt.Printf("After 5, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 6
    fmt.Printf("After 6, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 7
    fmt.Printf("After 7, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 8
    fmt.Printf("After 8, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 9
    fmt.Printf("After 9, capacity %v\n",len(c))
    c <- 10
    fmt.Printf("After 10\n")
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}
```

Comment: The operating system schedules threads. The Go runtime schedules goroutines on those threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am still a bit confused admittedly. I thought the echo function would output the channel buffer in chunks of 3. So: Main program execution  with goroutine echo spawned, then sending 1,2,3; At the time 4 is tried to send to the channel, a context switch happens to echo and it reads the contents of the buffer until empty. Then the context switches back again to Main for the next round. etc...? 
Maybe I am too simplistic about how scheduling works here?

Comment: @MartinX: you're just assuming magic which isn't there. The only control you have over goroutine execution is at synchronization points, which can be provided by blocking channel operations and mutexes (an of course other more complex types build from the primitives in the sync package, like `WaitGroup`  and `Cond`)

Comment: @JimB: Ok, but why is that magical? I assumed that having a buffered channel that is full would constitute such a 'synchronization point' as a further send operation is not possible so a switch to a different goroutine is necessary and the scheduler picks then one (quasi randomly as I have read in other posts)? Another assumption of mine: As long as there is no need for switching to a different goroutine, there will be no switch.

Comment: @MartinX: because you are assuming the `echo` goroutine is going to wait patiently until the buffer is full, empty it, then wait again. The goroutine will simply run whenever it can, whenever it's scheduled (which is likely be in parallel on multi-core systems, or on separate OS and hardware threads). Yes, the buffer being full may be a synchronization point for the sending goroutine, but the buffer never even gets full if the receiver reads them faster than they can be produced.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks that was helpful.